# Significance annotation in facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to annotate the plot below in a pairwise fashion - in each facet compare corresponding `samples` in the `variable`. Essentially comparing `CTR` from  `pos` to `CTR` from `neg` and so on. I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my data and plots:

```
library(ggpubr)

#data.frame
samples <- rep(c('LA', 'EA', 'CTR'), 300)
variable <- sample(c('pos', 'neg'), 900, replace = T)
stim <- rep(c('rp','il'), 450)
population <- sample(c('EM','CM','TEMRA'), 900, replace = T)
values <- runif(900, min = 0, max = 100)
df <- data.frame(samples, variable, stim, population, values)

#test and comparisons
test_comparisons <- list(c('neg', 'pos'))
test <- compare_means(values ~ variable, data = df, method = 'wilcox.test', 
group.by = c('samples', 'stim', 'population'))

#plot
ggplot(aes(x= variable, y = values, fill = samples), data = df) + 
 geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(0.85)) +
 geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', position = 
 position_dodge(0.85), dotsize = 1.5) +
 facet_grid(population ~ stim, scales = 'free_x') +
 stat_compare_means(comparisons = test_comparisons, label = 'p.signif') +
 theme_bw()
```

[image: plot]

This only produces 1 comparison per facet between pos and neg instead of 3...What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
samples <- rep(c('LA', 'EA', 'CTR'), 300)
variable <- sample(c('pos', 'neg'), 900, replace = T)
stim <- rep(c('rp','il'), 450)
population <- sample(c('EM','CM','TEMRA'), 900, replace = T)
values <- runif(900, min = 0, max = 100)
df <- data.frame(samples, variable, stim, population, values)

#test and comparisons
test_comparisons <- list(c('neg', 'pos'))
test <- compare_means(values ~ variable, data = df, method = 'wilcox.test', 
                  group.by = c('samples', 'stim', 'population'))

#plot
ggplot(aes(x= variable, y = values, fill = samples), data = df) + 
geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(0.85)) +
geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', position = 
             position_dodge(0.85), dotsize = 1.5) +
facet_grid(population ~ stim+samples, scales = 'free_x') +
stat_compare_means(comparisons = test_comparisons, label = 'p.signif') +
theme_bw()
```

[image]

Hope this will rectify your problem

Comment: I don't want to restructure the figure - just add the necessary annotation, which you have removed altogether.

Comment: now draw it again with the code, i commented the line before

Comment: Even though this changes how the figure looks, it still does not work. Annotation is still only in the `CTR` facets.